# Is half of the area of a Fibonacci triangle a congruent number?

Tags: number-theory

A Fibonacci triangle is a triangle with integer area and sides whose lengths are Fibonacci numbers. An example of a Fibonacci triangle is the triangle whose sides have lengths (5,5,8). Is half of the area of a Fibonacci triangle a congruent number ? (A congruent number is a positive integer which is the area of a right-angled triangle with rational sides.)

For the triangle (5,5,8) the area is $n=12$, and $\frac{n}{2}=6$ is a congruent number. Indeed, the right-angled triangle with sides $(3,4,5)$ is a half of the Fibonacci triangle $(5,5,8)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Corrected - thanks to Daniel Fischer)

If a triangle is made from 3 Fibonacci numbers $a \le b \le c$, then since we must have $c < a + b$ (in any triangle), it must be that the Fibonacci numbers are actually $F_n, F_n, F_k$ where $1\le k \le n+1$ and the triangle is isosceles.

Divide the isosceles triangle along its line of symmetry.

Since the area is assumed to be an integer, and $A = \frac12 b \times h$, it follows that the height must also be a rational number, so that half the area is just the area of right angled triangle with rational sides, and must then automatically be a congruent number.

Comment: $F_n,F_n,F_k$ for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n+1$ are the possibilities. That doesn't change the argument, however.

Comment: Ah yes (too much wine tonight) - but it still has to be isosceles, I think, so ...

Comment: Right, see edited comment.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you. Are there any other Fibonacci triangles known ?

Comment: Not sure yet - I will investigate ...